# Getting Kubernetes Config Map values into application.properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

In our project we are deploying our Spring Boot based microservices into Azure using Azure Kubernetes Service and we have a Jenkins Job that creates ConfigMaps with appropriate DB names using Azure CLI . Now I want to get the values of DB Names from the ConfigMap created by Jenkins in my Spring Boot application.properties .
Jenkins job uses following code to create a configmap in AKS

```
sh '''
     kubectl --kubeconfig ./temp-config create configmap generic ${PSQL_CONFIG} -n "${HEC_NAMESPACE}" \
     --from-literal=hec.postgres.host=${PSQL_SERVER} \
     --from-literal=hec.postgres.dbNames=[${DB_NAMES}] \
     --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl --kubeconfig ./temp-config apply ${DRYRUN} -f 
   '''
```

Now to get the value of variable DB_NAMES in my Spring Boot app ,

**1. Should I create a configMap inside a Spring Boot project and load the DB Values ?**

**2. Or should I set the DB_NAMES variable in the application.properties  like
hec.postgres.db-name={DB_NAMES}**

Once I have DB_NAMES values populated then I can use the way I want in my Code
Please let me know which approach is good

Comment: You can use `envFrom` to map all configmap values to env variables. in spring boot the env variable `HEC_POSTGRES_DB_NAME` is the same as the java param `hec.postgres.db-name`.

Comment: Can u please give me an example

Comment: @ronan Have you tried to look into [k8s official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)?

Comment: From your question : " Should I create a configMap inside a Spring Boot project and load the DB Values ?" AFIK  configMap  is part of kubernetes and deployment. It would setup environmental and configuration files inside your kubernetes pod/container.  With configMap (see k8s doc)   you can provide a "DB_NAMES" as an environmental variable inside your container and your spring-boot apps can read it the same way as any env vars locally (not on k8s). there is plenty of examples on the subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, define `DB_NAMES` variable and value in configmap object and load the values from configmap as environment variables inside the container. use those environment variables in the springboot properties file.

Comment: Thank you , can u please show an example